# Different Values in Form Inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, post

I have a simple HTML form that works with a PHP script (to process the values).

For some reason it's not working correctly. After many tests, I inspect the mark-up for the form and I find:

```
<form id="delete_item_3_form" action="upload/delete_item.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="item_id">
<input type="hidden" value="test" name="item_info">
</form>
```

As it should be. Please note that the values for the inputs are ***hard-coded***.

However, if I go to the browser console (I am using Chrome) and write:

```
$('#delete_item_3_form');
```

I get:

```
<form id="delete_item_3_form" action="upload/delete_item.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="item_id">
<input type="hidden" value name="item_info">
</form>
```

As you can see the value from the second input, item_info, is empty. Both inputs have a name.

I am not new to Form Handling but I have never seen this. The page mark-up shows one thing in a form, and a simple jQuery call to the same form shows another thing.

I have nothing, on my scripts, changing the value of the inputs.

The form is submitted by the press of a button. Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('#delete_item').click(function()
{
    $("#delete_item_3_form").submit();
});
```

How is this happening?

Comment: I don't think jquery live updates the DOM as you type in values. What you are seeing is the DOM state when jquery parsed it the first time. But when you query you'll always get the updated value.

Comment: The values are not typed by the user, they are hardcoded in this example.

Comment: And the problem is, when I query I get an empty value in "item_info". And nowhere in my script do I change the value of the "item_info" input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another form in the page with the same ID.

Comment: I know that normally you should not have more than one element with the same id, but wouldn't jquery return an array of these if there are many on the page, or does it stop at the first one found (by assuming the above)?

Comment: It will only return the first one.

Comment: Exactly. And the first one had nothing set on its "item_info" input.